# hide an element if one of the siblings is empty

Tags: jquery, hide, children

I need to hide div 'email' content if the div 'name' is empty. I did this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.media-contact').each(function() { 
        if ($(this).children('.name').text()===''){
         $(this).children('.email').hide();
        }
    }

});
```

But this is not working. There will be multiple such media-contacts, and not all will have the name div filled up with a value, so just the static text "Email" shows up and makes it ugly. I want to loop through each media-contact and check if 'name' is empty and if it is, then hide 'email'..please help..

```
<div class="media-contact">
        <div class="name">
            Bill Bero
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            Communications and Media Relations Specialist
        </div>
        <div class="email">
            <a class="rc-link" href='mailto:will.kero@canalliance.org'><span><img src="/sites/dev/style%20library/images/design/icons/icon_email.png" alt=""/><em>EMAIL</em></span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="phone">
            <span class="baec5a81-e4d6-4674-97f3-e9220f0136c1" style="white-space: nowrap">
            219-661-3099, ext. 2
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't know if that's your full code or what, but you're missing a closing `)` after `...text()===''` so it should be `...text()===''){`

Comment: fixed that, still not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.media-contact').each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).children('.name').text()) === '') {
        $(this).children('.email').hide();
    }
}​);​
```

See this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wGc3Z/)** with one name present and the other missing.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing text() to an empty string is iffy at best, and probably would behave differently in different browsers.  Checking for ":empty" should work better, although depending on how the page is rendered there might still be a text node with a newline in it or something.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.media-contact').each(function() { 
        if ($(this).children('.name').is(":empty")) {
         $(this).children('.email').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this didn't work either..can trimming the value of .name fix it?

Comment: You could try it...  $.trim($(this).children('.name').text()) == ""

Answer (score 0):

Try [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/t7cNS/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.media-contact').each(function() { 
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.find(".name").html().trim() == "") {
            $this.find(".email").hide();
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an idea. use toggle and a boolean.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.media-contact').each( function () {
        $(this).find('.email')
            .toggle( $.trim( $(this).find('.name').text() ) !== '' );
    });
});
```